# How to show these projectiles?

Tags: classical-mechanics, projectile-motion

A golfer stands on a flat beach at a distance $b$ from the foot of a cliff of
height $h$, where $b>\sqrt{3h}$, and hits a golf ball of mass $m$ towards the cliff with an initial speed $v_{0}$ and an angle of projection $\frac{π}
{6}$ above the horizontal.

**(i)** Neglecting air resistance, show that the cannon ball will clear the top
of the cliff provided $$v_{0}^{2}>\frac{2gb^{2}}{\sqrt{3}(b-\sqrt{3h})}$$

**(ii)** Assuming that condition (1) holds and there is a large flat field at
the top of the cliff, find the time at which the ball will hit the field, and show that the speed of the ball at this time is $$\sqrt{v_{0}^{2}-2gh}$$

Comment: How did the golf ball turn into a cannon ball?

Comment: It would help if you supplied your thoughts and attempts.

Comment: Sorry, it's meant to be a golf ball. And sorry for not providing any thoughts, but that is precisely why I am asking, because I have no idea and I'm not a mathematician. Would I make $b=\sqrt{3h}$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: 
$$
F = m (\ddot{x}, \ddot{y}) = (0, - m g)
$$